# How do I select a table from another table column?

Tags: sql

I have a table for seats at a venue but there are multiple venues. I could create one long table with an id for each venue next to each seat but that could make a 2000 long mixed table of venues and seats. So I thought I would create one table for each venue containing their own seating. Such as:

```
tickets

id | venue_name | seat_id

venueA

seat_id    | section    |    row | seat_number
```

So I'd like to select the venue table from venue_name ("venueA") and the seat_id. Such as

`SELECT seat_id from (select venue from tickets(venue_name));`

What I'm trying to capture is the seat_id for a venue so I know which section, row and seat is being requested. The section, row and seat information, as well as the number of seats, can be different for each venue.

I need to be able to identify a seat at VenueA while keeping that separate from the same seat at VenueB.

If that makes sense. This is my first foray into doing sql beyond simple design and interfaces to other people's work. Specifically I'm using postgresql.

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result.

Comment: Why not devide it into tables like: venue, seat, ticket, movie and then use basic foreign key - primary key relations? Like ticket should not have a venue name but a venue id (foreign key) and the name of the venue should be in the venue table

Comment: Using a separate table for another class which is otherwise like an existing one is rarely a good idea.  Just add a venue_id column and be done with it.   Two or more tables in a database with identical structure is almost always a pain-in-the-a** degenerate deoptimization.

Comment: @wallyk Perhaps you are right, and that was my original intention, but my lack of experience is showing.

Comment: Imagine what a hassle it would be if there were 4,000 active venues.

Comment: @wallyk That is a very good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design is badly done, which is why you're running into this issue. Instead of separate tables for each venue, you should simply have a table of venues. The seats table can then have a venue ID along with the seat information. Something like:

```
Venues (venue_id, venue_name, etc.)
Seats (venue_id, seat_id, section, row, seat_number)
Tickets (venue_id, seat_id, ticket_id, etc.)
```

Instead of "ticket_id" for Tickets, you might want to just have an "event_id" that relates to your events and that should uniquely identify any ticket assuming that your system doesn't have any strange business requirements. Also think about the possibility of non-reserved seating if that applies - a ticket might not actually apply to a "seat". That would change the architecture of the tables as well.

If you're going to be doing more of this sort of database design then you should definitely take time to read up on database design and normalization. It's not a trivial thing and the effects of a poor (or good) database design are **huge** on software development.

Comment: I have to read through your idea but it sounds like what I already have, or close to it. My issue may be lack of confidence and experience causing doubt. I have studied what you suggested. I've just not had to do it much myself all these years.

Comment: Small comment, better name the primary key of the table "id" and not "tablename_id". So Seat(id,venue_id,section,row,seat_number)

Comment: @Hogan What I show in my question is what I was thinking of doing; breaking the venues off into their own tables. I don't have that in my original design.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a schema that included such tables like Venue, Seat, Event and Ticket.  I would model Ticket such that it had an EventId and SeatId, an Event would contain a VenueId, a seat would contain a VenueId also.

--- edit to include explanation around testing ---

Apologies if this sounds derogatory, but you can use Explain in PostGre to check the performance of your queries and optimise where appropriate.  I would load the DB up with dummy data, possibly have indexes on EventId and VenueId in your child tables to begin with.  The documentation for EXPLAIN is here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: This is exactly what I have but I was concerned with having one table containing a mix of different venues with different seats. This can get quite large cause venueA may label rows by letter while venueB may use numbers and then each may have a different count of seats. My concern may be more from my lack of experience doing this.

Comment: There are no problem having lots of records in one table, databases are prepared for this. Just create all the proper indexes and you are good to go.

Comment: Dont worry about large numbers yet that is where databases are for ;) When the numbers are getting large like a couple of million tickets a day then you need to look at a complete different design (search: non relational database)

Comment: @M.Suurland -- That is not true, we have a DB which grows by 2-3 million a day here and it is relational.  Scale has little to do with non-relational -- use case has everything to do with it.

Comment: @Hogan I do not agree with you, when scaling becomes a key aspect, taking in mind to choose between a rational or non-rational database/design is an important subject to keep in the back of your head. I am trying to point this out to Rob (show him alternatives). since he making key design decisions now